# this в Fragment

Tags: java, android

Всем Привет! Почему `this` подсвечивается красным в Фрагменте?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private NewsAdapterParse NewsAdapterParse;
private ArrayList<NewsItemParse> NewsItemParse = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    NewsAdapterParse = new NewsAdapterParse(NewsItemParse, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(NewsAdapterParse);
    Content content = new Content();
    content.execute();
    return rootView;
}

private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
        NewsAdapterParse.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            String url = "https://sate.info/";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("article");
            int size = data.size();
            Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
            Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
            Log.d("size", ""+size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                String imgUrl = data.select("article")
                        .select("div.entry-image")
                        .eq(i)
                        .attr("data-bg");

                String title = data.select("h2.entry-title")
                        .select("a")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text();

                String detailUrl = data.select("h2.entry-title")
                        .select("a")
                        .eq(i)
                        .attr("href");

                NewsItemParse.add(new NewsItemParse(imgUrl, title, detailUrl));
                Log.d("items", "img: " + imgUrl + " . title: " + title);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `Fragment` не наследуется от `Context`, в отличии от `Activity`.

Используйте метод `requireContext()`

Comment: Можно добавить, что на версиях спорт-библиотек до 27 или овсем без них можно использовать метод getActivity() в качестве контекста